# top three are visible on the dashboard

Tags: dashboard

I have been working on the dashboards. I noticed that if I have more than three tables/charts only the top three are visible on the dashboard.

I have searched both google and SF help and this definitely seems to be a known problem. Apparently there are workaround,s but the ones I have tried haven't worked.

Do you know of any work around that would in theory work for us?

Comment: That’s the feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SF Lightning, you can have up to 6 table/charts on the Home Page Dashboard. 3 is the limit for SF Classic.

> [Create Beautiful Dashboards Using a New, Feature-Rich Editor (Lightning Experience)](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_apex_job.htm&type=5)

As for workarounds, you would need to use visualforce.